# Remove specific tag icon from Stack Overflow

Tags: stack-overflow

One of my favorite tags on Stack Overflow has been infused with a "sponsor" from a company I detest.

How can I remove this "ad" from my viewing experience?

Comment: Let me guess... you're a ReSharper user? :)

Comment: Nahh.. when I'm developing I just don't like using 3rd party controls with non-intuitive object models. One such company which produces such controls seems to have sponsored a great majority of .NET based tags.

Comment: I just get irritated at sites that deliberately mislead and lie to their users. SQL Server is not made by RedGate.

Comment: Funny, I thought about this today. I'm not against advertising, but those tag logos screw with my eyes.

Comment: Questions about the Stack Exchange software belong on [meta] or, better, [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about Stack Overflow should be asked on [Stack Overflow Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use firefox would be to install the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/2108/) plugin and have it add a `display:none` to the `sponsor-tag-img` this would remove all the sponsors tags.

Comment: Thanks for the tip: Is there any equivalent for Chrome?

Comment: Yes, there's an extension called "Chrome Stylist". I tested it, and this tip does work with it. You can get Chrome Stylist here: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/pabfempgigicdjjlccdgnbmeggkbjdhd

Comment: Thanks Joe - further to this, http://userstyles.org/styles/23926 is a direct link to a Stylist script that will remove the icons on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an ad/image blocker, to remove the unwanted image(s). There are many for the different browsers.

Comment: Ad Blocker Pro for one